# Kohana ORM - Empty Result on User Rights

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Im building a user management system based on 2 pillars.

**1. Roles**

Each user have multiple roles.

**2. Rights**

Every role consists of one or more rights.

Users and roles are working fine in my attempt:

```
class Model_Auth_User extends ORM {

protected $_has_many = array(
    'roles'       => array('model' => 'Role', 'through' => 'roles_users'),
);...}


class Model_Auth_Role extends ORM {

protected $_has_many = array(
    'users' => array('model' => 'User','through' => 'roles_users'),
);...}
```

I am trying to add some Roles and Rights the same way:

```
class Model_Auth_Role extends ORM {

protected $_has_many = array(
    'users' => array('model' => 'User','through' => 'roles_users'),
    'rights' => array('model' => 'Right','through' => 'role_rights'),
);



class Model_Auth_Right extends ORM {

protected $_has_many = array(
    'roles' => array('model' => 'Role','through' => 'role_rights'),
);
```

The access to the roles works fine like this:

```
$roles = $user->roles->find_all(); //works fine
```

However, the access to the Rights of a Role always delivers an empty result:

```
$rights = $user->roles->rights->find_all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $user->roles i collection

```
<?php
$rights = [];
foreach($user->roles->find_all() as $role){
 $rights[] = $role->rights->find_all();
}
```